# How to open new window in Asp.net or C#?

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

I am working on asp.net here. I need to open my url into my new window from there, I am providing my user url and password and I need to login to a particular site.

Everything is working fine, the problem is its not opening in new window but I had searched in Google I got no of articles but I don't I am doing something wrong to open a window. I had tried my best but I just stuck.

This is what I had tried: here I have a link button you can check here and I had succeed in login to my site but I need to open this into new window

```
<asp:LinkButton  runat="server" Text='new window'  onclick="btnlink_Click"></asp:LinkButton>
```

And here my code behind page code goes here:

```
public void btnlink_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            CrossPost cp = new CrossPost();          
            cp.AddField("username", "saddusattu");
            cp.AddField("password", "password");
            cp.PostDataToForm(Url: "http://www.Estateslogin/index.php", FormName: "form",OpenLinkNewWin:true);    

        }
```

I am calling below methods:

```
 public void PostDataToForm(string Url, string FormName, bool OpenLinkNewWin)
            {

                try
                {
                    var strWindowFeatures = "location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";

                    var win =  "_blank";
                    string newwindow = "<script>window.open('" + Url + "','" + win + "', '" + strWindowFeatures + "');</script>";

                    if (OpenLinkNewWin)
                    {
                        System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(newwindow);
                    }     

                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Clear();

                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("<html><head>");
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write(string.Format("<form name=\"{0}\"  method='post'  action=\"{2}\" >", FormName, "post", Url));
System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</form>");

            System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write("</body></html>");
                    System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
}
```

The above code exist have to open in new window using `System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Response.Write` only that's why I am having problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a half-dozen functions named `RegisterClientScriptBlock`, each with a slightly different purpose and use case.  One of them is probably what you want.  For example, if the `LinkButton` in an update panel and you are using a `ScriptManager`, the static function, [`ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338357.aspx) would probably work well.